# drush make fails on patch download

Tags: drush, version-control

drush make unsuccessful, because download of patch fails  -

I have (apparently equal) boxes, on one my drush make fails, on the other it's fine.

```
Unable to download                                                [error]
https://drupal.org/files/l10n_update-proxy_support-1863544-1.patch.
drush make FAILED. Exiting...
```

I am behind a proxy but checked that it is not the basic problem. http_proxy is set and I can use wget on shell.

2nd approach is to change the URL to http.

UPDATE: Found now patching itself fails. just wondering why it works on the other box.

UPDATE2:

I created a test branch and removed all modules except for the failing one. And tried another module version where a similar patch exists. Here are both entries:

```
;projects[l10n_update][version] = "1.x"
;projects[l10n_update][patch][1863544] = "http://drupal.org/files/l10n_update-proxy_support-1863544-1.patch"
; ISSUE: https://drupal.org/node/1863544#comment-6832354

projects[l10n_update][version] = "1.0-beta3"
projects[l10n_update][patch][1791100] = "http://drupal.org/files/l10n_update.inc-1791100.patch"
; ISSUE: https://drupal.org/node/1791100#comment-7422500
```

here i have now:

```
l10n_update-7.x-1.0-beta3 downloaded.                             [ok]
http---drupal.org-files-l10n_update.inc-1791100.patch retrieved      [notice]
from cache.
(Stripping trailing CRs from patch.)                                 [notice]
patching file '<html>l10n_update.inc'
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
Hunk #1 FAILED at 257.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file
'<html>l10n_update.inc.rej'
Unable to patch l10n_update with l10n_update.inc-1791100.patch.   [error]
```

Is it a patch format drush cannot handle ??

Comment: Can you `wget https://drupal.org/files/l10n_update-proxy_support-1863544-1.patch` ? If patching itself fails, compare files patched and software versions.

Comment: I think the patch and module versions correspond. see my update. I will examine that patch now

Comment: I will post a fresh question.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85909/drush-make-fails-to-apply-my-patch-level-1-from-local-gitweb-cache-issues